# Why does webrtcbin's jitter buffer size affect latency when there is no jitter?

Tags: gstreamer

Just wondering if anyone knows why there is sometimes a linear correlation between the `latency` value (jitter buffer size in ms) in webrtcbin as added latency on a smooth network?

It seems that with some downstream elements, it adds latency linearly. As far as I understand, this is the max time packets will stay in the buffer. However packets should leave the buffer as soon as they can.

The working theory is that some elements (such as the compositor) are influenced somehow by `gstrtpjitterbuffer.c`.

Doc ref: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html?gi-language=c#webrtcbin:latency

Testing done:

Changing the value on some applications from 200 to 100 causes a 100 ms reduction on the pipeline's latency on a stable network with no packet loss and very low jitter.

Answer (score 2):

> However packets should leave the buffer as soon as they can.

This is not how the jitter buffer works. The idea of the jitter buffer is that you start using the data *only* after some delay. E.g. you set the jitter buffer to 100 ms. This means 100 ms after the first packet arrives, you start playing it back. If the next packet is randomly delayed for 50 ms in the network, you play it back 50 ms later after arrival rather than 100 ms. This way you can tolerate delays up to 100 ms without changing the intervals between the packets.

This is similar to how buffering works on YouTube or Twitch. They start playing the video after accumulating some amount of buffer, so you have to wait, but then there is no stall in case of jitter. On Twitch you can enable the "low latency" mode which reduces the amount of buffer so you watch the video with lower delay, but there is a higher chance of stall in case it takes longer to deliver the packet than the length of the jitter buffer in milliseconds.

> Changing the value on some applications from 200 to 100 causes a 100 ms reduction on the pipeline's latency on a stable network with no packet loss and very low jitter.

It does not matter that the network has low jitter now. Jitter buffer protecting you against the event of the delay suddenly becoming higher. Jitter is essentially the unpredictable variation in latency.

Comment: I thought the latency value was the maximum value the buffer will wait for a missing out-of-sequence packet. This is not the case? So even a stream of perfectly in-order packets will be delayed by the `latency` value? I suppose my high level question is how we see a linear delay when there is no jitter whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, the stream will be delayed by at least the `latency` value.

Comment: So then even when the buffer is holding say, packets [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10] that it knows are in order via their seq numbers, it still will not release them for the fixed amount, or even a portion of them. I sort of get why that might be the case...

Comment: Yes, jitter buffer is not a reordering buffer. It tries to ensure uniform rate of playback. If you play the packets as soon as they arrive, there will be variation in playback speed in presence of jitter, this is why the jitter buffer tries to avoid.